# Finding period of $f$ from the functional equation $f(x)+f(x+4)=f(x+2)+f(x+6)$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

How can I find the period of real valued function satisfying $f(x)+f(x+4)=f(x+2)+f(x+6)$?

Note: Use of recurrence relations not allowed. Use of elementary algebraic manipulations is better!

Answer (score 10):

You are given that $f(x)+f(x+4) = f(x+2)+f(x+6)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Replace $x$ with $x+2$ to get $f(x+2)+f(x+6) = f(x+4)+f(x+8)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Thus, $f(x)+f(x+4) = f(x+2)+f(x+6) = f(x+4)+f(x+8)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Subtract $f(x+4)$ from the left and right side of the last equation to get: $f(x) = f(x+8)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Important note: This tells you that $f$ is $8$-periodic, but $8$ may not necessarily be the minimum period. For instance, $f(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ satisfies $f(x)+f(x+4) = f(x+2)+f(x+6)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, but has period $2$.

Comment: Well, there's no minimum period in that sense, since $\sin(n\pi x)$ also satisfies the equation, but an interesting question would be, what is the minimum period that can be deduced from the functional equation?

Comment: Actually, $\sin\frac\pi4x$ shows that in that sense, $8$ is the minimum period.

Answer (score 4):

Observe, since 
$$
f(x)+f(x+4)=f(x+2)+f(x+6),
$$
we can substitute $x+2$ for $x$ to get 
$$
f(x+2)+f(x+6)=f(x+4)+f(x+8).
$$

Equating these, we know that $f(x)=f(x+8)$.